# Unexpected Error message

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer with headless chrome to execute the following script
https://gist.github.com/mbierman/5b3e671fa4e848eec899ff486d0cdc26

Which does what I want it to do, however I get the following errors:

```
(node:1374) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (/Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:73:21)
    at <anonymous>
(node:1374) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1374) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
+ duration=32
```

Are these problems with my puppeteer script or with the puppeteer distribution? I think I am running the latest.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: The problem is that you are making an async call and after 3 seconds  it hasn't heard back from it thus raising an error which is not caught by that function which made the call. A promise should have 2 handlers, 1 for resolve and another for reject. Your code is missing the latter.

Comment: I can't post the entire gist. Won't let me. See https://gist.github.com/mbierman/5b3e671fa4e848eec899ff486d0cdc26

Comment: @SamuelToh thanks. I guess what is confusing me (besides the fact I'm new to puppeteer) is the error above is not in my code—it looks to be in the puppeteer code NavigatorWatcher.js:73:21. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks like it needs refactoring with proper async-await:

- `process.on("unhandledRejection")` should be on top of the file.
- `page.setViewport` should be awaited.
- `page.goto` can use a param `{waitUntil: 'load'}` to wait till page loads.
- `page.click` should be awaited.
- `page.on('dialog')` should be invoked when you create the page.
- `browser.close` should be awaited.

Not certain but it can even be that the page you are trying to load is problematic.

- Does `http://192.168.0.1/login.asp` load in browser?
- Is it behind a proxy?

If you ask and try to solve one by one, you will have the working code.

Learn more about async await and promises [here](https://javascript.info/async). There are other resources available, but it's best if you learn about the nature of async before you work with it.

Comment: Thank you, @Md. Abu Taher I made the changes you suggested except for page.on('dialog') — wasn't sure what you meant. Can you elaborate? 
When I awaited the page.on('dialog') things stopped working. Works fine without the await. Any idea what's going on? 

yes, login.asp loads in a browser. This is a page for my router admin. 

FYI revised code https://gist.github.com/mbierman/5b3e671fa4e848eec899ff486d0cdc26

Comment: could be my mistake about awaiting page.on('dialog'). Does it work properly without only that change?

Comment: Yes seems perfect with everything else. Well, as I said I didn’t understand your suggestion about page.on. So I didn’t test that.